# How to fetch data from database,store it in a variable and perform arithmetic operations?

Tags: php

Here I have created one product table and one order table.I want that as soon as order is placed,product id is entered the product name and price will be shown on the form,and as soon as quantity is given,the total price will be calculated and accordingly the stock for that particular product id will be updated accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Place Order</title>
<h1><center>ORDER MATTERS</center></h1>
</head>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "<marquee><h1> Order have been placed successfully.</h1></marquee>" ;
mysql_select_db("in", $con);


$sql="INSERT INTO orders         (Name,Phone,Address,pid,Item,Price,Quantity,Total,Payment)
 VALUES('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Phone]','$_POST[Address]','$_POST[id]','$_POST[item]','$_POST[Price]','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[Total]','$_POST[option]')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
<body>
<form name="f1" action="orders.php" method="post">
<table style="background-color:#CCFFFF" border="4" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td> <input type="textbox" name="Name" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone:</td>
<td bgcolor="#3399FF"> <input type="textbox" name="Phone" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCFF00">  <input type="textbox" name="Address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Product id:</td>
<td> <input type="textbox" name="id" /></td><tr>
<td>Item:</td>
<td> <input type="textbox" name="item" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Price:</td>
<td> <input type="textbox" name="Price" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qty.:</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFCCCC"> <input type="textbox" name="quantity" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total:</td>
<td> <input type="textbox" name="Total" /></td>
<td><? php echo $total; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Payment Method:</td>
<td>
<select name="option" id="option">
<option selected value="Cash on Delivery">Cash on Delivery 
<option value="Cheque">Cheque
<option value="Online Payment">Online Payment</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"  /> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
//Trying the stock concept
$y=$_POST[id];
$qty=$_POST[quantity];
$x=(select price from products where id=($y));
$p=$x;
$total=$p*$qty;
(select stocks from products where id=$y)=$stockold;
$stock=$stockold-$qty;
stocks=$stock;
update stocks in products where id=$y;



?>
```

Comment: you code is really really horrible/terrible, deprecated api, sql injection vulnerability, even you have space between `<? php`, also you know you can formate your code properly its not a big deal just use space bar or tab!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? There isn't a clear question to me here. What issues are you having trying to accomplish this, or are you just asking for someone to write your code for you?